# $\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{pq}$

Tags: number-theory, summation, logarithms, analytic-number-theory

I was given that $\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p}$ = $\log\log x$+O(1).

I need to show that $\sum_{pq\le x} \frac{1}{pq} = (\log \log x)^2 + O(\log \log x)$.

Here we go:

Break the sum into two sums: $\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p}\sum_{q\le \frac{x}{p}} \frac{1}{q}$

Using what I was given: $(\log \log x +O(1))(\log \log \frac{x}{p} +O(1))$

Log Rules: $(\log \log x +O(1))(\log( \log x - \log p) +O(1))$

Algebra: $\log \log x \cdot \log(\log x - \log p) + O(\log \log x)$

From here I am lost. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $q$? Is it related to $p$? Are $p$ and $q$ primes?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Both primes, not necessarily distinct.

Comment: Yep, fixed that too. Looks like I shouldnt do math when im exhausted. Everything looks good now.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean that you are given that
$$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p=\log(\log(x))+O(1)\tag{1}
$$
and that you want to estimate
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{pq\le x}\frac1{pq}
&=\sum_{p\le x}\sum_{q\le x/p}\frac1{pq}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{p\le x}\sum_{2\le q\le x/p}\frac1{pq}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{p\le x/2}\frac1p\left(\log(\log(x/p))+O(1)\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{p\le x/2}\frac1p\log(\log(x)-\log(p))+O(1)\sum_{p\le x}\frac1p\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{p\le x/2}\frac1p\left[\log(\log(x))+\log\left(1-\frac{\log(p)}{\log(x)}\right)\right]+O(\log(\log(x)))\tag{6}\\
&=\log(\log(x))^2+O(\log(\log(x)))+\sum_{p\le x/2}\frac1p\left[\log\left(1-\frac{\log(p)}{\log(x)}\right)\right]\tag{7}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: write explicitly as a double sum
$(3)$: note there is no $q=1$ case
$(4)$: apply $(1)$ to the sum in $q$
$(5)$: incorporate the left sum into the error term from the right sum
$(6)$: apply $(1)$ to the error term
$(7)$: $\sum\limits_{x/2\lt p\le x}\frac1p\le\log(2)$ and $(1)$ imply $\sum\limits_{p\le x/2}\frac1p=\log(\log(x))+O(1)$

It can be shown that
$$
\sum_{p\le x/2}\frac1p\left[\log\left(1-\frac{\log(p)}{\log(x)}\right)\right]=O(1)\tag{8}
$$
but I don't see how it can be shown using just $(1)$.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The question is about summing over primes $p,q$, not just arbitrary integers.

Comment: @barto: I had assumed we were summing only over primes. Otherwise, $(8)$ would be $O(\log(x))$. Furthermore, $(1)$ would not hold.

Comment: But then why do you treat the case $q=1$? I must be missing something...

Comment: @barto: good point. That is just incorporated into the error term, so it does not matter. It is now removed.

Comment: How did you prove $(8)$? I think you mean something like this? $$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{1}{p}\left(\log\left(1-\dfrac{\log p}{\log x}\right)\right)=-\log\log x+O(1)?$$
Since I ran programme and it seems that $$\sum_{p\le x}\dfrac{1}{p}\left(\log e\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{\log p}{\log x}\right)\right)=O(1).$$

Comment: Summing by parts and using the Prime Number Theorem, indicates that the sum over primes is similar to $$\sum_{k\lt x/2}\frac1{k\log(k)}\log\left(1-\frac{\log(k)}{\log(x)}\right)$$ then approximating this sum by an integral, we get $$\begin{align}\int_2^{x/2}\frac1{t\log(t)}\log\left(1-\frac{\log(t)}{\log(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t&=\int_{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(x)}}^{1-\frac{\log(2)}{\log(x)}}\frac{\log(t)}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\&\ge\int_0^1\frac{\log(t)}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\&=-\frac{\pi^2}6\end{align}$$ The sum over primes for $x=10000000$ is $-1.3744663$.